# Put a unicode symbol at the end of geom_line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to at a unicode symbol at the end of my geom_line graph in ggplot2.

So far I tried it with adding a geom_point layer but it of course sets it at every point.

How can I set a "latin cross"  `"\u271D"` at the end of each line?

"R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)"

Packages

`library("tidyverse")  library("scales")`

My df:

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 30L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
"18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
"29", "30"), class = "factor"), time_point = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L), levels = c("0", "24", "48", "72"), class = "factor"), avg_rag = c(257600, 
11653000, 161100, 295303000, 151300, 6288000, 319800, 67233000, 
190000, 3326000, 4050900, 97663200, 233900, 10203000, 253100, 
325400, 2438700, 24111900, 405300, 319400, 1598100, 17572700, 
370900, 2510100, 143632700, 323900, 2521100, 3371700, 18591900, 
468600, 92084100, 317700, 155815100, 228200, 26215100, 260500, 
270400, 302800, 156915100, 104400, 172215100, 80900, 133516700, 
167800, 4845700, 22993100, 146900, 2938700, 19033100, 100500, 
47300, 134416700, 169400, 17296700, 62500, 929600, -68800, 1251600, 
265000, 1956600, 193700, 946600, 153100, 1032600, 15145000, 134300
)), row.names = c(NA, -66L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

My code so far

```
ggplot(longer_t1, 
       aes( x= time_point, y= avg_rag, group=id,colour = id ))+
  geom_line(linewidth= 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = pretty_breaks(),
  )+
  scale_x_discrete(name = "time in h"
  )+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_label(aes(label=Label))+
  geom_point(
    data = longer_t1,
    aes(y = avg_rag, x = time_point),
    shape = "\u271D",
    size= 5,
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.07)
  )
```

Comment: Your code does not run. Show which packages you have loaded. Also, `Label` is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to define a new data frame that only contains the data points where a cross should be drawn.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

label_data <- longer_t1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_tail(n = 1)
```

You can then use the `data` argument of `geom_text()` (or `geom_label()` if you prefer) to use that new data frame to create the crosses.

```
ggplot(longer_t1, 
       aes(x = time_point, y = avg_rag, group = id, colour = id))+
  geom_line(linewidth = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks()) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "time in h") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(data = label_data, aes(label = "\u271D"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think we simultaneously posted the answer. But thank you for taking the time! How can I remove the squares around the symbol that appear in my solution?

Answer (score -1):

[image]Nevermind I found a solution based on [This question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/putting-labels-for-only-the-first-and-the-last-value-of-data-in-r-and-ggplot2/49927)

```
# slice for last point

longer_last <- longer_t1 %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(which.max(time_point))

# graph
library("scales")

ggplot(longer_t1, 
       aes( x= time_point, y= avg_rag, group=id,colour = id ))+
  geom_line(linewidth= 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "average radiance (p/sec/cm²/sr)",
    breaks = pretty_breaks(),
  )+
  scale_x_discrete(name = "time in h"
  )+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_point(
    data = longer_last,
    aes(y = avg_rag, x = time_point),
    shape = "\u271D",
    size= 5,
    position = position_nudge(x = 0.07)
  )
```

I still have a question though: How do I remove the square around the cross? To only have the pure symbol?

Comment: If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: Your code in the answer does not produce boxes. The boxes come from `geom_label()` which you used in your question.

Comment: And a question for my personal learning: How do I avoid getting down-votes? I presented my solution?  (I am really just curious and thankful for all hint how to use this platform better) Thank you for all advice

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Stibu.  Strangely, I still get the boxes. Can it be connected to a font setting or something similar ?

Comment: Are you sure you are running exactly the code from the answer? Since I don't get the boxes it is hard to figure out what is going wrong. Do you get the boxes when you run the code from my solution (which uses `geom_text()` instead of `geom_point()`). Maybe restart your R session?

Comment: Yes, the exact same code. Tried your advice and restarted R session. No changes. But thank you.

Comment: And with my solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem.

Comment: As suggested [by this user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77943061/15564212) it might be system-dependent font display. As suggested, I replaced the latin cross unicode with the daggar (†, `\u2020`).